# Problema con caso de clases y métodos

Tags: c#, windows-forms

**Presentado el siguiente ejercicio**

Dados dos números decir si son primos gemelos. Dos números son primos gemelos si siendo primos, existe una diferencia entre ellos de 2, ejemplo:

> ```
> +-----------+-----------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
> | Entrada 1 | Entrada 2 |                               A la salida explicación                                |
> +-----------+-----------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
> |         2 |         3 | No son gemelos Tanto 2 como 3 son números primos pero la diferencia entre ellos es 1 |
> |         3 |         5 | Si son gemelos Ambos son números primos y la diferencia entre ellos es de 2          |
> |         7 |         9 | No son gemelos Aunque la diferencia es de dos el número 9 no es primo                |
> +-----------+-----------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
> ```

Realicé lo siguiente pero no se en donde esta el error.

**clase y metodo**

```
namespace PrimosGemelos {
 public class Primouno {
  private int n1;
  private int n2;
  private bool esprimo;

  public int N1 {
   get;
   set;
  }
  public int N2 {
   get;
   set;
  }
  public bool EsPrimo {
   get;
   set;
  }

  public Boolean EsPrimo1(int n1, bool numpri) {
   {
    int a = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i < (n1 + 1); i++)
     if (n1 % i == 0)
      a++;
    if (a != 2)
     return false;

    else
     return true;
   }
  }
  public Boolean EsPrimo2(int n1, bool numpri) {
   {
    int a = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i < (n2 + 1); i++)
     if (n2 % i == 0)
      a++;
    if (a != 2)
     return false;

    else
     return true;
   }
  }
 }
}
```

Pero no encuentro a forma de llamarlos en el `btncalcular`esto es lo que he realizado:

```
namespace PrimosGemelos
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        Primouno MiPrimouno = new Primouno();
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {              
            {
                MessageBox.Show("No son GEMELOS");                

                MiPrimouno.N1 = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text);
                MiPrimouno.N2 = Convert.ToInt32(textBox2.Text);               
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: gracias por la edicion davlio

Comment: Estamos para ayudarnos, ¿Qué quieres mostrar en tu formulario `Form1`?, solo veo que capturas los valores. Hay variables (`esprimo`, en `EsPrimo2` no usas `n1`) y parámetros (`numpri`) que no usas en tu método. ¿Qué es realmente quieres hacer a nivel general?

Comment: Necesito crear una clase y un metodo para los 2 numeros que se ingresaran los cuales debo validar en un boton calcular si son numeros primos. soy nuevo en progra y en una clase de metodos y clases, no he aprendido mucho

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estimado te envio una solucion que puede ayudarte

```
using System;

namespace PrimosGemelos
{
    public  class Numero
    {
        public  int Valor { get; set; }
        public  bool Primo { get; set; }
        public  Numero(int valor)
        {
            Valor = valor;
            Primo = EsPrimo(valor);
        }
        private bool EsPrimo(int num)
        {
            int n = (int)Math.Sqrt(num);//Raiz Cuadrada
            int a = 2;
            if (num == 1 || num == 2)
                return true;
            for (int i = 2; i < n; i++)
                if (num % i == 0)
                    return false;
                else
                    a++;
            return true;
        }
    }
    public class PrimoGemero
    {
        public int Numero1 { get; set; }
        public int Numero2 { get; set; }
        public bool PrimoGemelo { get; set; }
        public PrimoGemero(int numero1, int numero2)
        {
            Numero1 = numero1;
            Numero2 = numero2;
            PrimoGemelo = CalcularPrimosGemelos();
        }
        private bool CalcularPrimosGemelos()
        {
            if (Math.Abs(Numero1 - Numero2) == 2 && (new Numero(Numero1)).Primo && (new Numero(-Numero2).Primo))
                return true;
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Y cuando realices el boton calcular usa este codigo

```
namespace PrimosGemelos
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            int a = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text);
            int b = Convert.ToInt32(textBox2.Text);
            PrimoGemero obj = new PrimoGemero( a,b);
            MessageBox.Show(obj.PrimoGemelo.ToString());
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias Estimado